# In Github, Actions stopped working at deploy stage while pushing and the error " Error: Process completed with exit code 1" was executed

Tags: github, jekyll, github-actions, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I pushed my files to github (.github.io) repo. Everything was going smoothly but, suddenly "Actions" stopped working in deploy stage
showing the error

> Error: Process completed with exit code 1

I'm not quite sure what the exact reason behind this is. Any help is much appreciated.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMIyU.png)

Github issue page link: [Issue description](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy/issues/655)

Please note, I was using Jekyll-chirpy theme for the website -shaeekh.github.io and was hoping to be hosted by github.

Comment: Please copy&paste error messages instead of linking them, because this allows people to search&find your question.

Comment: I've copied the error message already mentioning " Error: Process completed with exit code 1"

Comment: Please copy and paste the whole message including with what is before the `Error: Process completed with exit code 1`